# FreeBSD 9.3 ImportError while installing py-MySQLdb

Tags: python, freebsd

I want to install py-MySQLdb but I always get the same lib error..
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

ImportError: /usr/lib/libz.so.6: unsupported file layout
*** [do-configure] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/databases/py-MySQLdb.
*** [install] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/databases/py-MySQLdb.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you mixed 32 and 64bit libraries.

I suggest cleaning up the wrong libraries (at least libz seems to be affected) and restoring them from backup/installation medium